# Internal Server Error Large Files

Tags: api, soundcloud

I'm using the Soundcloud API in one of my sites and the documentation says that the max upload file is 500MB, every time that i try to upload a file larger than 1mb, the system returns me a 500 error (Internal Server Error). Files smaller than 1MB works fine.

I'm using PHP 5, curl and Soundcloud API.

Thanks for your attention!

Hugs.

Comment: If my response was correct, please consider marking it the answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

The 500mb limit is with *their* API, sending files to them. However, if your server is initially receiving the file (and then sending to soundcloud), your server also has limits. This is usually defined within your php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 50M
post_max_size = 50M
```

Alternatively this *may sometimes* be overwritten in your htaccess if you don't have access to your ini file:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
php_value post_max_size 50M
```

You'll also need to increase the script execution time using [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) or in your php.ini set max_execution_time (15 minutes?) and the memory limit:

```
max_execution_time = 900
memory_limit = 64M
```

You'll need to be careful and consider the implications of increasing these limits. Their designed as security mechanisms. For example, if you increase the memory_limit and PHP consumes too much memory, current processes will move to swap and degrade performance and possibly crash the machine or even worse corrupt data; max execution time will allow the script to linger on for longer, so if you have a poorly written script it could hang indefinitely or for at least 15 minutes (like I have above) and ultimately reach its memory limit or the limits of the machine - not to mention having multiple scripts running and consuming resources cumulatively.